# How to resolve 'SOAPAction None does not match an operation.' error when using zeep in python?

Tags: python, wsdl, soap-client, zeep, soapheader

I am trying to use zeep 3.4.0 to consume a SOAP api using python but it is giving me below error:

> zeep.exceptions.Fault: The given SOAPAction None does not match an operation.

The SOAPAction is absent from my wsdl file definition.
Below is a snippet of the wsdl method I need to call

```
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
          <wsdl:operation name="testStatus">
             <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
             </wsdl:input>
             <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
             </wsdl:output>
          </wsdl:operation>
```

Using the below code snippet to call this api:

```
    request_data = {
            "testStatusRequest": {
                "testStatusUpdate": {
                    "ID": "BD38A5232CDA425BA7F5296BDAAF3DB31595617610"
                }
            }
    }
    client = Client('http://localhost/aff/DynamicProcessManagerSvc? 
   wsdl',wsse=UsernameToken(user,token))
    client.service.testStatus(**request_data)
```

Comment: Run: `python -mzeep <wsdl>` and share the output for operation `testStatus`

Comment: @Tarique PFB the output of the operation :                                                                                testStatus(testStatusRequest:  ns1:testStatusRequestType) ->

Comment: And what's the definition of `testStatusRequestType`?